# Bind selected value in dropdown during the edit time in asp.net Mvc5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, html-select

My controller code:

```
 ViewBag.ddlprincepal = new SelectList(objentity.ddlPrincipal(), "PrincipalID", "PrincipalName");

  ViewBag.ddlprincepalselected = new SelectListItem { Text = inventoryDetailobj[0].PrincipalName, Value = (inventoryDetailobj[0].PrincipalID).ToString(),Selected=true };
```

My view the code:

```
  @Html.DropDownList("ddlprincepal",ViewBag.ddlprincepal as SelectList ,ViewBag.ddlprincepalselected as string , new { @id = "ddlprincepal" })
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you can do this by Jquery and it has only few lines of code. Since I don't know what text you are having before edit, I assume something such as **Name**.

We need to first select the dropdownlist and then on the edit button click, we need to send the text value into the dropdownlist as its value.

So the code:

```js
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


$('.EditBtn').on('click',function(){

// this is the text value you show in label form (before edit)
var lblObj = $("#lblName");

// this is your dropdown while edit mode.
var dropdwn = $("#ddlprincepal");

dropdwn.val(lblObj.html());  // this will bring your text value into the dropdownlist while edit mode.

});
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

i have found the solustion

View//

@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.PrincipalID, ViewBag.ddlprincepal as SelectList, "--select--", new { @id = "ddlprincepal" })